# How to retrieve documents from firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve my documents from firebase but I am receiving a error that is crashing my preview but it allow my app to build successfully but its not allowing me to view my user data on the device it just a blank screen. I am wondering is this code outdated and why am I receiving a error that allow my app to build anyway but doesnt let me see anything ?

> Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

```
guard let user = try? snapshot?.data(as: User.self) else {return}
```

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

class AuthViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var userSession: Firebase.User?
    @Published var currentUser: User?
    
    static let shared = AuthViewModel()
    
    init() {
        
        userSession = Auth.auth().currentUser
      fetchUser()
    }
    

 func fetchUser() {
        guard let uid = self.userSession?.uid else { return }
     
       Collection_Users.document(uid).getDocument { snapshot, _ in
           guard let user = try? snapshot?.data(as: User.self) else {return}
           self.currentUser = user
           
           
        }
```

Comment: First, ban `try ?` from your vocabulary.  Always use `do/try/catch` and at least `print` any resulting error.  Make sure you are using the latest `FirebaseFirestoreSwift`.  Also, are you sure that `userSession` is not `nil` when `fetchUser` is called?  Have you debugged this code with a breakpoint?

Comment: im not sure how to use do/try/catch is this the right way ?  @Paulw11                do{
               guard let user = try? snapshot?.data(as: User.self) else {return}
               
               self.currentUser = user
               
           }catch{
               print(error.localizedDescription)
           }

Comment: No `do { let user = try snapshot?.data(as: User.self) self.currentUser = user } catch { print(error) }`.  Don't print `error.localizedDescription` it is typically less informative than just printing `error`

Comment: does this info answer your question: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data  A tutorial here: https://medium.com/swift-productions/swiftui-fetch-data-from-firestore-and-display-it-in-a-list-a8084f875b00